# Unable to install Unicorn on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, unicorn

I am unable to install Unicorn on localhost (OS -- Windows 8).

```
>gem install unicorn
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing unicorn:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    E:/software/Ruby200-x64/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for CLOCK_MONOTONIC in time.h... yes
checking for clockid_t in time.h... yes
checking for clock_gettime() in -lrt... no
checking for t_open() in -lnsl... no
checking for socket() in -lsocket... no
checking for poll() in poll.h... no
checking for getaddrinfo() in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h,netdb.h... no
getaddrinfo required
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=E:/software/Ruby200-x64/bin/ruby
        --with-rtlib
        --without-rtlib
        --with-nsllib
        --without-nsllib
        --with-socketlib
        --without-socketlib


Gem files will remain installed in E:/software/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/kgio-2.9.2 for inspection.
Results logged to E:/software/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/kgio-2.9.2/ext/kgio/gem_make.out
```

Why? What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?

I'm using Ruby on Rails 4.1.4 btw.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm having this same error...

Comment: @frozenheart try specifying in your gemfile like this: `platforms :mswin do
  gems 'unicorn'
end`

Answer (score 3):

[Unicorn does not have native Windows support](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/).